# AngularJS & Ionic - Minified error $rootScope:infdig, not minified works ok

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, minify

So, I have tons of js files, one per controller, one per service, one for directives and one for filters.

After checking everything was declared with inline array notation I minified, and I have the next problem:

```
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
file:///Users/id/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E17B3C6B-9153-4DDE-84B7-DC37B32AA216/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C2894260-5ED1-471E-AE80-B17FEC539F22/TheApp.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8890:32
$digest@file:///Users/id/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E17B3C6B-9153-4DDE-84B7-DC37B32AA216/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C2894260-5ED1-471E-AE80-B17FEC539F22/TheApp.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23108:35
$apply@file:///Users/id/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E17B3C6B-9153-4DDE-84B7-DC37B32AA216/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C2894260-5ED1-471E-AE80-B17FEC539F22/TheApp.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23333:31
file:///Users/id/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E17B3C6B-9153-4DDE-84B7-DC37B32AA216/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C2894260-5ED1-471E-AE80-B17FEC539F22/TheApp.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:25059:42
completeOutstandingRequest@file:///Users/id/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E17B3C6B-9153-4DDE-84B7-DC37B32AA216/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C2894260-5ED1-471E-AE80-B17FEC539F22/TheApp.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13732:15
file:///Users/id/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E17B3C6B-9153-4DDE-84B7-DC37B32AA216/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C2894260-5ED1-471E-AE80-B17FEC539F22/TheApp.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14112:33
2015-09-15 14:32:01.624 TheApp[34155:625632] ERROR:Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D, file:///Users/id/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E17B3C6B-9153-4DDE-84B7-DC37B32AA216/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C2894260-5ED1-471E-AE80-B17FEC539F22/TheApp.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13736
```

I don't know why this problem is happening, If I use the non minified file, everything works like it should be, but using the minified file I get this infinite digest errors..

I have the `ng-strict-di` directive added, so no problems with annotations.

What can be causing this behavior?

I use gulp to do the job, this is the task in gulpfile: (just in case needed)

```
var src_paths = [
    'src/**/*.js'
];
var dist_path = 'www/js';

gulp.task('dist', function() {
    gulp.src(src_paths)
        .pipe(concat('app-test.js'))
        .pipe(header(banner, {
            pkg: pkg
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist_path))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename({
            extname: '.min.js'
        }))
        .pipe(header(banner, {
            pkg: pkg
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist_path));
});
```

If you need more specifics please ask, all help is welcome.

Comment: you need ng-annotate before uglify.

Comment: I believe I don't need it, like I said, i'm already annotating everything with inline array notation, and that's what ng-annotate does I believe. Unless there is something else it can do?

Comment: ok, as long as you know what you are doing. and yes, you are right, infdig does not directly related to annotation.

Comment: That's exactly my point, I don't know why I get this weird behavior with minification.. I guess i'll get into it again later, i've tried everything and went through thousands of lines of code and still can't find the reason. If and when I fix it, i'll answer this question. If someone has suggestions on what to look for, i'd appreciate it. Thanks for your time @YOU.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find the answer?

Comment: I'm sorry, i have not, but probably many missing `;`, that's what i'm finding so far in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error.  I was getting infinite digest errors when using angular minified files and no errors when using the non minified version.  Also the error message that was being logged by angular had a non-working url.

Ultimately, I found out that the problem was with using a method at the activation of controllers that would use `$window.location.assign('#/mypage/page1')`;.  I fixed it by changing to using `$location.path` instead.

I am assuming that it was causing some race condition with the app router that was only visible in the minified version.  May not be the same problem you are having, but just wanted to share my experience.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, perhaps it will fix someone else's bug,, but that's not the problem i'm having, i'm not using any of those methods. Thanks anywyas :]

Comment: I am having the same issue. What if even if you might not be using those functions something else that you are using (directive / factory / service / etc) is using it? I assume you were not able to solve this yet right?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.  The app was working fine when non-minified, but not when minified. And I was getting this same error in the console.

The root cause in my case was with one of the ui-router state's resolve.

It errored out when the resolve was like this:

```
resolve: ['afactory', function (afactory) {
   //....
}]
```

It worked when the resolve was changed to:

```
resolve: {
  somename: ['afactory', function (afactory) {
    //....
  }]
}
```